# Show that Non abelian group of order $21$ is of the form $\{x,y|o(x)=7,o(y)=3, yxy^{-1}=x^2\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Since $|G|=21=7\times 3.$

$n_7=1+7k|3$. So no of Sylow 7 subgroup is unique and hence normal.

$n_3=1+3k|7$. Then $n_3=1$ or $ 7$. If $n_3 =1$ then $G$ is cyclic. If $n_3=7$,then, Let $H$ be the subgroup of order $7$ and $K$ be one subgroup of order $3$.Let $H=<x>,K=<y>,$

Since $H$ is normal then $yxy^{-1} \in H$. Then $yxy^{-1}=x^i$ where $0\leq i<7,$ 
I cannot contradict the fact that $yxy^{-1}$ cannot be equal to $x^4$.
Please help me.

Comment: Please use MathJax to type set your question. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Here is help: follow the posts [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1106283/group-of-order-21-is-abelian-or-not?rq=1) on this site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing that a group of order $21$ (with certain conditions) is cyclic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154709/showing-that-a-group-of-order-21-with-certain-conditions-is-cyclic)

Comment: If $yxy^{-1}=x^4$, then $y^2xy^{-2}=yx^4y^{-1}=x^{16}=x^2$, so instead of $y$, pick $y^2 =y^{-1}$.